# Using knife tool to cut all around a an object

Tags: knife-tool

Please see the following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PK36W234WV0 specifically @ 12:40 where the knife tool us used to cut not only the top face but all around the cube.

When I try and do this I only seem to get a cut on the top face. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my premature question. I should have paid attention to the various options available with the knife tool!

Turns out that pressing Z activates the cut through option which in effect creates a loop cut around the object.